# When are Sitecore Pages created?

Tags: presentation

Our Google Search Appliance is going crazy, reindexing each of our pages several times a day. The Google support specialist asked us if our pages were being generated dynamically or not. I know that each page in Sitecore is created dynamically from a template. However, what I don't know is **when** that page is created.

Is each content page created at publish time, or is it created when a visitor requests the page?

Comment: Are you caching your pages/components? Pretty sure the page is "created" each request, but the caching might do something different.  There are a lot of settings on GSA'S to throttle indexing. If this is a production environment, shouldn't really matter if the GSA is indexing constantly.  You do want to make sure you have the user agent excluded to Sitecore Analytics.

Comment: Do not try to determine when the page is created... that's impossible. Instead, only try to realise the truth: there is no page.  Then you will see it is not Sitecore that must bend, it is the GSA.

Comment: Hahaha it took me a moment..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pages are "Created" when a user requests that page, but that doesn't mean that the content is *new* each time.

You can setup caching on your renderings to limit the load on the server each time a page is requested.

For the Google Search Appliance it is probably looking for last updated and cache control headers to check if the page has been modified and needs to be reindexed. For this you will need to decide what content on the page you want the crawler to care about and then make sure that when it changes, you update the last modified date. Also you should make sure that any cache control headers sent in the response have an appropriate expiry date/time on them.

If your response is set to not cache, then everytime the crawler hits the page, it could see it as "updated" and re-index it.

Comment: Great explanation! I have seen funky behavior when not caching responses, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add onto what @RichardSeal said, "pages are 'created' when a user requests that page" because all "pages" managed in Sitecore are virtual.

When you publish, Sitecore simply promotes your content from "master" to "web" (think "authoring" to "live") by copying your content from the master database to the web database (or whatever name you gave your publishing target). There aren't any behind-the-scenes file-creation operations performed that create ASPX files, directory hierarchies (site structure), etc. As such, when a user requests a page, Sitecore resolves the URL and finds the item that would exist at the requested path, then uses the item's Presentation Details to render the HTML for that "page".

As Richard described, you can set up caching on your renderings to help optimize this process and improve performance to prevent slow load times from holding up 3rd party crawlers.